# Does MediaRecorder API support on IOS

Tags: ios, safari, mediarecorder

I have this code. This works fine on Windows and Android but I cannot catch all the words I am saying. I can get only a few words. When I checked the document, I could see this API works on Safari as well. What is that problem? Why this MediaRecorder API doesn't work on iOS?

```
function startRecording() {
        hideSpinner();
        hideRating();
        hideRatingSets();

        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
            .then(function (stream) {
                audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
                analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
                analyser.fftSize = 256;
                var source = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
                source.connect(analyser);
    
                dataArray = new Float32Array(analyser.fftSize);
    
                mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    
                mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (event) {
                    if (event.data.size > 0) {
                        audioChunks.push(event.data);
    
                        // Update the wave view
                        drawWave();
                    }
                };
    
                mediaRecorder.onstop = function () {
                    var audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: 'audio/wav' });
    
                    // Save the audio data to a variable for later use
                    savedAudioData = audioBlob;
    
                    // Save the audio or do further processing
                    //console.log('Audio saved:', audioUrl);
                    transcribeAudio(audioBlob);
    
                    // Clear audioChunks after processing
                    audioChunks = [];
                };
    
                // Start the mediaRecorder
                mediaRecorder.start();
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.error('Error accessing microphone:', error);
            });
    }
```

I want to know why is that not working on iOS

Answer (score 0):

The MediaRecorder API is supported since Safari Version 14.1: https://caniuse.com/mediarecorder